# sql join with nested where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I've got a problem trying to join two tables, sample tables I have are as follows

Orders Table (Odr)

```
Order_No Item No  Order_Type  Req_Qty
100        A          2        45
101        B          1        32
102        F          2        23
103        A          4        23
104        C          3        14
105        B          5        43
```

Item Location Table (Loc)

```
Item_No   Location       Qty
A            X           100
A            Y           200
B            X           150
B            Y            50
C            X            75
C            Y           150
F            X           250
F            Y            60
```

What i want to see is, Location X's qty for each item of order types 1, 2 and 3 and for orders where Req_Qty is larger than 0
like below,

```
Order_No Item No  Order_Type  Req_Qty X_Qty
100        A          2        45     100
101        B          1        32     150
102        F          2        23     250
104        C          3        14     75
```

now ive written a query like below for this but i feel like its not giving me right results

```
select Odr.*, Loc.Qty
from Odr 
inner JOIN Loc
ON Odr.ITEM_no = Loc.ITEM_no
where (SOPTYPE = '1' and Req_Qty >0
 or SOPTYPE = '2' and Req_Qty >0
 or SOPTYPE = '3' and Req_Qty >0) AND Loc.Location = 'X'
```

could someone pleas check this for me if this is the correct way to get the result i want

thanks

Comment: Add parentheses...

Comment: @jarlh - I dont think it will make any difference in this case

Comment: I feel like query is fine

Comment: My guess is it's about `LEFT JOIN` or even `outer apply` and additional filters on order_type and probably something else.

Comment: What does *but i feel like its not giving me right results* mean?

Answer (score 1):

the query looks fine. but you could make it more readable:

```
select Odr.*, Loc.Qty
from Odr 
inner JOIN Loc
ON Odr.ITEM_no = Loc.ITEM_no
where (SOPTYPE = '1' or SOPTYPE = '2' or SOPTYPE = '3') 
  and Req_Qty > 0 
  and Loc.Location = 'X'
```

or

```
select Odr.*, Loc.Qty
from Odr 
inner JOIN Loc
ON Odr.ITEM_no = Loc.ITEM_no
where SOPTYPE IS IN('1', '2', '3') 
  and Req_Qty > 0 
  and Loc.Location = 'X'
```